# D3: how to create a bar chart by row with a csv file

Tags: csv, d3.js, bar-chart

I just started playing around with D3 and created my first bar chart using a .CSV file.

The csv file looked as follow:

```
"browser","marketshare"
"firefox", 20
"IE", 45
"Chrome", 30
"opera", 5
```

using the following code for my rectangles would result in 4 rectangles with the height of 20, 45, 30, 5

```
.attr("height", function(d) { return d.marketshare; });
```

now I have a slightly different file

```
"browser","2001","2002","2003","2004"
"firefox",20,19,22,25
"IE", 45,40,39,35
"Chrome", 30,33,35,37
"opera", 5,4,5,4
```

What I'd like to do is create 5 separate bar charts one for firefox, IE, Chrome and opera.
Let's say I want to create one for firefox. How can I change: function(d), so that it will create rectanlges for the year 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004 and that only for firefox.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not just create if then statements checking the browser around the code block? Another option is changing the data accessed depending on the browser and just updating the .data() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you could potentially do this by only changing the logic in your `attr` function, it will be much cleaner to divide up your data before that point. You want four arrays (one for each browser) each containing only height values.

This is how you do it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Data Sort</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var browsers = [];
    var w = 500;
    var h = 100;
    var barPadding = 3;
    d3.csv("data/browsers.csv",
            function(error, rows) {
                rows.forEach(function(r) {
                    browsers.push({
                        name: r.browser,
                        values: [r['2001'], r['2002'], r['2003'], r['2004']]
                    })
                });
                browsers.forEach(function(b){
                    render(b);
                });
            });

    function render(browser) {
        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);

        svg.selectAll("rect")
                .data(browser.values)
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                    return i * (w / browser.values.length);
                })
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return parseInt(h - d);
                })
                .attr("width", (w / browser.values.length) - barPadding)
                .attr("height", function(d) {
                    return parseInt(d);
                })
                .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
                    var rgbColor = "rgb(" + Math.round((Math.random()*255)) +
                            ", " + Math.round((Math.random()*255)) + ", "  +
                            Math.round((Math.random()*255)) + ")";
                    return rgbColor;
                });

        // Add a label to each SVG.
        svg.append("text").text(browser.name).attr({"x": 0, "y": 30});

        // NOTE THIS RENDER FUNCTION IS MISSING THE UPDATE AND EXIT PHASES. WE
        // ARE DOING EVERYTHING IN THE ENTER PHASE - WHICH MEANS IT WILL ONLY
        // WORK ON STATIC DATA.
    }

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the problem is that this is an acceptable solution for a small file, but I have larger file and splitting this file into 100 small files is not really a good solution, I think.

Comment: I'm not saying split up the file. I'm saying split up the array into many smaller arrays. One for each bar chart.

Comment: aha I see, sorry for the misunderstanding. As I mentioned at the start of my question, I am very new to D3. Could you maybe tell me how to do this and/or if possible provide a link to a tutorial?

Comment: Added some code, which assumes you have a data/browsers.csv file.